# Find the last name in the 18th position after cycling through the HTML link list for 7 times using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, data-extraction

I am not able to understand how this python code is used to get the output.

[HTML file](http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Sayeda.html)  <----Click here

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = raw_input('Enter URL - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)<----Here we are reading the .html file word by word

Count_ = raw_input('Enter Count - ') <----------
Position_ = raw_input('Enter Position - ')<-----We are asking user to input the values of "Count", and "Position" variables.

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a') <----Extracting all anchor tags using the Beautiful Soup program.
final = ""
curpos = ""
```

---

I don't understand the logic, even though that is the purpose of this code.

```
count= int(Count_) + 1
while count > 0 :
    pos = 0    
    for tag in tags:
        if pos == int(Position_) - 1:
           curpos = tag.get('href', None)
           break
        pos = pos + 1
    final = curpos
    url = str(curpos)
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    tags = soup('a')
    count = count - 1
print final
```

Can somebody help me out with this?

Answer (score -1):

So I think the snippet is pretty straightforward, so I'll highlight those parts that might be critical for you.

You get three user inputs, namely: `url`, `Count_` and `Position_`.

From the `url` you extract all anchor tags and then loop through them until you get to the desired position which is `Position_ - 1`.

Then you extract the href link of the actual anchor and store it in `curpos`.

You again assign `curpos` to the previously defined `url` and again open it, read it, extract its anchor tags, then decrement `count` and continue this loop until `count` is greater than 0.

After the loop quits you print out variable `final` which is the same as the last `curpos` which is the href link of the last found anchor tag at position `pos`.

Basically the script goes deeper and deeper in a sequence of urls based on their href of the anchor tag at the specified position.